# Security model - SharePoint 2010 Silverlight web part calling WCF service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, security, sharepoint

I have an interesting situation that I haven't been able to crack. Here is the environment that my Silverlight application runs in.

We have a SharePoint 2010 intranet that is the main host for the application. On a web part page, we have a Silverlight web part that contains the application. We use the Client Object Model to deduce who the logged in SharePoint user is. The users of this application access the SharePoint site OUTSIDE of the AD domain that they use to login; meaning they have an AD account, but their computers are part of various domains. The Silverlight application makes calls to a WCF service over https via SOAP protocol.

The question is, how do I secure the services so that the only valid requestor is the Silverlight application when being called from inside the context of a logged in SharePoint user?

Each end-user has an AD account that is created for them. The SharePoint site is an extranet that requires each user to login using their AD credentials. However, no end-user is accessing a site from a computer that is part of the domain.

I've attempted using Windows Authentication, but we have a requirement that the user must not be prompted to login (to the web services) after they have already logged into SharePoint. I've attempted using the Client Object Model to "pass" authentication/credentials to the service, but no luck there.

We have to disable Anonymous Authentication before we go to live, so I've got to figure out a way to secure the services but not make the users login a 2nd time inside the application.

Answer (score 0):

out of the box you cant, silverlight cant delegate to any external service for security reasons. What you can do is to secure your WCF channel via some other method (certificate based for example) and send through the current username manually. On the SharePoint end you can then impersonate the user.

It will be quite a fiddly thing to get going though :)